# Encode url string to Dictionary In my case: Some value have = inside

Tags: ios, swift, urlencode, urldecode

I'm trying to convert decode to dictionary from the below url encoded string. The normal method of doing so is given below. In my case it is not working. Also i need to remove any character like `\u{05}`

```
let params = str.components(separatedBy: "&").map({
    $0.components(separatedBy: "=")
}).reduce(into: [String:String]()) { dict, pair in
    if pair.count == 2 {
        dict[pair[0]] = pair[1]
    }
}
```

My url encoded string is

```
"id=sfghsgh=sbfsfhj&name=awsjdk_fs\u{05}"
```

I'm expecting result as

```
{ 
"id" = "sfghsgh=sbfsfhj",
"name" = "awsjdk_fs"
}
```

How it is possible to achive?

Comment: Use URLComponents. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55601459/1187415

Comment: works fine. but when the key contains some unicode, the answer is falied, updated my question

Comment: What result would you expect for the updated query string?

Comment: I need to remove the unicode character also from keys

Comment: All characters are “Unicode characters.” What exactly do you want to remove? More details are needed.

Comment: \u{05} this character

Comment: Only `\u{05}`? What about `\u{04}` or `\u{10fff}`? Again: please describe the task *exactly,* otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: all this kind of characters to be removed

Comment: Your query string is not valid: `id` pair value has two `=`. That's why your `pair.count == 2` condition fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piggyback on [`URLComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents):

```swift
var components = URLComponents()
components.query = "id=sfghsgh=sbfsfhj&name=awsjdk_fs"

components.queryItems
// => Optional([id=sfghsgh=sbfsfhj, name=awsjdk_fs])

let list = components.queryItems?.map { ($0.name, $0.value) } ?? []
// [("id", Optional("sfghsgh=sbfsfhj")), ("name", Optional("awsjdk_fs"))]

let dict = Dictionary(list, uniquingKeysWith: { a, b in b })
// ["name": Optional("awsjdk_fs"), "id": Optional("sfghsgh=sbfsfhj")]
```

If you need a `[String: String]` rather than `[String: String?]`:

```swift
let list = components.queryItems?.compactMap { ($0.name, $0.value) as? (String, String) } ?? []
// [("id", "sfghsgh=sbfsfhj"), ("name", "awsjdk_fs")]

let dict = Dictionary(list, uniquingKeysWith: { a, b in b })
// ["name": "awsjdk_fs", "id": "sfghsgh=sbfsfhj"]
```