# Group same named NSURLComponents queryItems into NSDictionary as array

Tags: objective-c

With no objective-C knowledge I am currently stuck at, what would be a simple task in other languages I know.

For a query string like this:

`name1=value1&name2=value2&name1=value3`

I need to end up with a NSDictionary in this shape:

```
@{
  @"name1": @{
    someField: @[
      @"value1",
      @"value3",
    ]
    anotherField: @YES,
  },
  @"name2": @{
    someField: @[
      @"value2",
    ]
    anotherField: @YES,
  }
}
```

In javascript I could solve this by:

```js
queryItems.reduce((result, item) => {
  resultItem = result[item.name] || {
    someField: [],
    anotherField: true,
  }
  resultItem.someField.push(item.value)
  return {
    ...result,
    [item.name]: resultItem,
  }
}, {})
```

I found this [How do I convert url.query to a dictionary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603220/how-do-i-convert-url-query-to-a-dictionary-in-swift) but I am stuck with Objective-C in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Check the function bellow. I hope I understand what you mean.

```
NSDictionary* queryItemsToDictionary(NSString* items) {
    NSURLComponents* components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:[@"?" stringByAppendingString:items]];
    NSMutableDictionary* result = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSURLQueryItem* item in components.queryItems) {
        NSDictionary* valueForItem = [result objectForKey:item.name];
        NSArray* someFieldValues = [valueForItem objectForKey:@"someField"];
        if (someFieldValues == nil) {
            someFieldValues = @[];
        }
        [result setObject:@{
            @"someField": [someFieldValues arrayByAddingObject:item.value],
            @"anotherField": @YES
        } forKey:item.name];
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is how you can try it:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = queryItemsToDictionary(@"name1=value1&name2=value2&name1=value3");
NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
```

Comment: thanks! I think I understand whats happening there. ObjectiveC does not have any higher order functions like reduce?

Comment: @philk You can find `reduce` in Objective-C [here](https://github.com/weijentu/Higher-Order-Function-ObjC).